# What is The meaning of org.json.JSONException in Android?

Tags: android, arrays, json, jsonexception

I am developing an Application of JSON object Which Returns data into ListView.

In That One Parameter Need to be passed which is Uid of User.

My Code for Async is:

```
class  AsyncCallWebServicereceiveHistory extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ReceiveHistory.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Loading");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl)
    {
        Log.v("receiveHistory","Do in BG-1");
        uid=global.get_user_id();
        try
        {
            HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://demo1.idevtechnolabs.com/RChatAPI/receive_history.php");

            List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uemail", uid));
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = null;

            response = client.execute(postMethod);
            final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            Log.v("Album ::","Response:::--->"+response.toString());
            Log.v("Album ::","Status Code:::--->"+statusCode);

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String LineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                stringBuffer.append(line + LineSeparator);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();

            //-------------CONVERT DATA TO JSON---------------------------------

            try
            {
                String myjsonstring = stringBuffer.toString();

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(myjsonstring);

                JSONObject jsonObj = null;

                jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                code = jsonObj.getString("code");
                receiveMsgData.clear();

                Log.v("Home ::","Code:::--->"+code);

                code="0";
                if(code.equals("0"))
                {
                    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                    {

                            jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            uname=jsonObj.getString("name");
                            uage = jsonObj.getString("age");
                            usex = jsonObj.getString("sex");
                            body = jsonObj.getString("country");
                            text= jsonObj.getString("text");

                            HashMap<String, String> tmp_album = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            tmp_album.put("receive_data", "Text");
                            Log.v("receive History","receive Data");
                            receiveMsgData.add(tmp_album);

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.v("Home ::","Call JSON Exception in get Album in List--->"+e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.v("Exception: Get get Album in List","Name-"+e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return code;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String code)
        {
            if(code.equals("0"))
            {
                Receive_History_Custom_Adapter adapter = new Receive_History_Custom_Adapter(getApplicationContext(), receiveMsgData);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            try
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                progressDialog = null;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // nothing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### And I got Following Exception:

```
Call JSON Exception in get Album in List--->org.json.JSONException: Value [] at 0 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

### My Json Responce Is:

```
[
    {
        "code":"0", "user_id":"21", "msg_id":"115", "name":"Sagar", "age":"18", "sex":"Male", "country":
        " India", "text":"hi", "photo":"demo.idevtechnolabs.com", "cnt":"1"
    },
    {
        "code":"0", "user_id":"18", "msg_id":"114", "name":"Ramani", "age":"20", "sex":"Male", "country":
        "Pakistan", "text":"hi", "photo":"demo.idevtechnolabs.com", "cnt":"1"
    }
]
```

Can anyone tell me what is the cause of this and how can I solve this please.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: post your json response if you can

Comment: `Value [] at 0 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject` Your json is a `JSONArray` but you are trying to convert it to J`SONObject`

Comment: Ok then How can I solve this @Raghunandan

Comment: @NiravDabhi sure that is the full json and post the stacktrace full and 2 for loops in no required    `for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){for(int i=0; i<4;i++)`

Comment: @NiravDabhi get rid of  `for(int i=0; i<4;i++)`

Comment: ya ofcorse i Had just put that for testing But I had already remove it @Raghunandan But the error is different.

Comment: @NiravDabhi then post the error that you get

Comment: I had already Posted the error In the question. @Raghunandan

Comment: @NiravDabhi you said a different error. i thought a differeent error to your previous one

Comment: @NiravDabhi it'l help if you keep the question updated, you ought to:)?! with the exact code you use and full logcat -> with line number of error that you get

Comment: The error is JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject. at line ***jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);***       But I dont Know How to solve it.

Comment: @NiravDabhi No, that is not your exact problem. Your code is fine if you are actually getting the json response that you specified. Check your response again- what you get in myjsonstring. Post the full logcat. I tried your code with that json, it works

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to add every item from `JSONArray` to the list of messages if the code of this item equals to `0`. If so, your code is wrong and it's easier to re-write it than just explain:

```
try {
    String myjsonstring = stringBuffer.toString();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(myjsonstring);
    receiveMsgData.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("code") == 0) {
            JSONObject data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            HashMap<String, String> tmp_album = new HashMap<String, String>();
            tmp_album.put("name", data.getString("name"));
            tmp_album.put("age", data.getString("age"));
            tmp_album.put("sex", data.getString("sex"));
            tmp_album.put("country", data.getString("country"));
            tmp_album.put("text", data.getString("text"));
            receiveMsgData.add(tmp_album);
        }
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.v("Home ::", "Call JSON Exception in get Album in List--->" + e.toString());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here we are iterating over the `JSONArray` and check if `code` is equal to `0`. If it's equal, we put the necessary fields to the temporary `HashMap` and then append it to the messages list.

Comment: 0 is not an int it is String Can you Help me according this. If Code returns 0 then the data should be Pass

Comment: @NiravDabhi Just try this code. String "0" can be parsed to `int`, so we are able to use `getInt`

Comment: It returns Null as a Code "0" so Exception is same.

Comment: @NiravDabhi In such a case show exact value of `myjsonstring`

Comment: Can you explain me What is the exzact reason for that error because I had tried alot but i Got the Same error all time.