# How to check JSON is empty in Android?

Tags: android, json, web-services, null

I am developing an Android Application which Fetch data from PHP Json.

**I fetch the data of json successfully From JSON** but my problem is **when JSON is Empty it stops the application.**

So I need to Know is **How to know if the JSON is NULL or Return Nothing** in ANDROID.

### My empty JSON is:

```
[[]]
```

How to check that with Coding.

Please send me your suggestions.

My Full Code is [**On This Link:**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808148/what-is-the-meaning-of-org-json-jsonexception-in-android)

Thanks Alot

Comment: How are you parsing it? any third party libray or default parser?

Comment: Just Default Parser with JsonString and JsonObject.

Comment: At which part is it stopping your application..? while parsing or after that?

Comment: jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);  stops And error is JsonObj can not converted in JSONARRAY

Comment: Surround it with a try throw block.

Comment: Already My code is in Try catch Block

Comment: Ya, but add the right catch block...

Comment: Use catch (JSONException e) .. if till u are facing same prob  than Please post your code here  ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808148/what-is-the-meaning-of-org-json-jsonexception-in-android My Code is here in my prev que. please check it out

Answer (score 2):

```
JSONObject myJsonObject = 
    new JSONObject("{\"null_object_1\":[],\"null_object_2\":[null]}");

if (myJsonObject.getJSONArray("null_object_1").length() == 0) {
    ... 
}
```

Comment: M getting null array in json as a output [[]]] then How it can be checked if no data found

Answer (score 2):

firstly you get key set of json.

```
 Iterator<Object> keys = json.keys();
```

then check if any key exist then your json contain some value.

```
if(keys.hasNext()){ // json has some value
```

}
else
{
// json is empty.
}

Comment: what is json? JSONObject or JSONArray? I cant Pass keys to JSONObject

Comment: I cant pass keys to JSONObject. Error is Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method keys() from the type JSONObject

Comment: read this link it will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154090/android-get-json-key-value

Answer (score 1):

try like this,

```
if (<Your JSONobj>!= null ){
    // do your parsing 
}else{

}
```

Comment: I m parsing the data from JSON to listview so if I check this condition first i initialise jsonobj=null; then how it works

Answer (score 1):

after getting json from url first check for null by simply execute the code:-

```
if(yourjsonobject!=null){

//write your code here

}else{e
enter code here
//json is null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) json string "[[]]" means not empty jsonAarray it means your Outer JsonArray contains one  element as JsonArray and your inner JsonArray is empty.

2) The reason your application is crashing/stopping is that JsonObject and JsonArray are incomptible types. You can not cast JsonArray to JsonObject. See 
[JsonArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) and
[JsonObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

3) You can always check the length of your JsonArray by 
[JsonArray#length()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#length%28%29) method.
also check 
[JsonArray#isNull](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#isNull%28int%29) if want to check wheter a JsonObject is NULL.

```
try {
    JSONArray object = new JSONArray("[[]]");
    if (object.length() > 0) {
        JSONArray inner = object.getJSONArray(0);
        if (inner.length() > 0) {
        // do something         
        }
    }           
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Got The error cannot convert from JSONArray to JSONObject

Comment: Please see the link in my question I had already posted the code in my prev question